# вывести в консоль содержимое папок с отступами

Tags: java, рекурсия

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить метод вывода содержимого папок в консоль так, что бы вывод выглядел как на картинке, т.е. лесенкой. Если в папке есть файлы, то вывод корректный. А если в папке лежит другая пустая папка, то выводит без отступа. Спасибо.

```
private static void doRecurs(File dir) {
        if (dir.isDirectory()) {
            File[] list = dir.listFiles();
                if (list != null) {
                    for (File name : list) {
                        if (name.isFile()) {
                            System.out.println("\tFile - " + name.getName());
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Directory - " + name.getName());
                            doRecurs(name);
                        }
                    }
                }
        } else System.out.println(dir.getName() + " не является папкой");
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно в doRecurs:

- Передавать уровень вложенности, увеличивая его при рекурсивном вызове на 1
- Генерировать строку-отступ, которая зависит от уровня вложенности

Пример:

```
    ...
    static String repeat(int n, String value) {
        return new String(new char[n]).replace("\0", value);
    }

    static void doRecurs(File dir, int level) {
        final String indent = repeat(level, "    ");

        if (dir.isDirectory()) {
            File[] list = dir.listFiles();
            if (list == null)
                return;

            for (File name : list) {
                if (name.isFile()) {
                    System.out.println(indent + "File - " + name.getName());
                } else {
                    System.out.println(indent + "Directory - " + name.getName());
                    doRecurs(name, level + 1);
                }
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println(dir.getName() + " не является папкой");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        doRecurs(new File(<путь до папки>), 0);
    }
```

Comment: Привет! спасибо  за ответ, помогло! Теперь подпапки выводятся как надо.

Comment: @nikolay4294, пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 0):

Недавно решил такую же задачу так:

```
public class RecursionUtil {
private static StringBuilder tab = new StringBuilder("");

public static void pathOutput(String path) {
    File[] catalog = new File(path).listFiles();

    for (File file : Objects.requireNonNull(catalog)) {
        System.out.print(tab.toString());
        if (file.isFile()) {
            System.out.println(file.getName());
        } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println(file.getName());
            tab.append("\t");
            pathOutput(path + File.separator + file.getName());
            tab.delete(tab.length() - 1, tab.length());
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Спасибо! очень полезный пример!